# Deleting a whole record from XML

Tags: android, xml, xpath, nodelist

I am trying to delete a node and its children from an XML file using XPath.  Here is what I tried but its not working.

Here is the xml:

```
<registration>
   <users>
     <name>abc</name>
     <class>10th</class>
     <email>demo@mail.com</email>
   </users>
</registration>
```

I am getting an email address from a user by searching the specific record for that email and then deleting it.

Here is the code:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//email[text()='" + sEmail + "']";
System.out.println(expression);
Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.NODE);
if (null != node) {
  Node pNode = node.getParentNode();
  nodeList = pNode.getChildNodes();
  for (int i = 0; null != nodeList && i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node nod = nodeList.item(i);
    if (nod.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      System.out.println(nod.getNodeName() + " : "nod.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
      Node cNode = nod.getFirstChild();
  nod.getParentNode().removeChild(cNode);                
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the exception I get:

```
04-03 15:39:18.274: E/AndroidRuntime(23163):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.InnerNodeImpl.removeChild(InnerNodeImpl.java:181)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
cNode.getParentNode().removeChild(cNode);
```

or

```
nod.removeChild(cNode);
```

Lets say `A` is the parent node of `nod`. What you are currently trying to do is to delete the child `cNode` from `A`, whereas you want to remove the child `cNode` from `nod`

**Update**

If you want to delete the whole `<user/>` record than your code can be much simpler. No need for deleting each and everyone child element by hand.

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//user[email='" + sEmail + "']";
System.out.println(expression);
Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.NODE);
if (node != null) node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
```

Comment: both statements worked fine, but the problem is that its only removing the text like abc, 10th and mail@demo.com , structure is not getting deleted, so in result the listview which iam generating after deleting nodes shows empty row in place of delete record

Comment: True, because you are trying to delete the text node from these elements. Try `nod.getParentNode().removeChild(nod)` to delete the element.

Comment: What is </user>? This is not valid XML... Also, could you please clarify what you _actually_ want as output (i.e. edit your question), this is not clear from the question. Your text looks like you want to delete the `<email/>` element, but your code suggest you want to delete the texts (or maybe the elements) of `<name/>`, `<class/>` and `<email/>` and now you are talking about something else.

Comment: <users> "</users>" . . . . I'll try to solve it , ur answer to this question is rite, thank u for ur time and help..

Comment: @AdilWaqar No need to accept an answer before it answers your actual question. I get the impression that you really want to delete the whole `<user/>` element. Is this correct? Than your code can be much simpler, see my updated answer.

Comment: yeah your are rite, , , and u did solved my problem, thanks again :)